# "not a valid pathspec" wit git-latexdiff

Tags: latexdiff, git

Do anyone know what's wrong here?

```
$ git-latexdiff --main main.tex master other-branch
/usr/bin/latexpand
fatal: empty string is not a valid pathspec. please use . instead if you meant to match all paths
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

Kind regards.